# RMarkdown: how to rotate table column headers

Tags: css, r-markdown

I'm trying to rotate table column headers in RMarkdown. Since I don't have an understanding of CSS my attempts so far have proven to be futile.

So, how can I rotate the table column headers?

Here is a minimal example for a table in RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    style: ./Table.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```

<div class="table-header-rotated">

```{r test, result="asis"}

kable(head(mtcars), "html")
```
</div>
````

And the CSS file was made from the code presented here: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Fapif

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you ever find an adequate solution to this issue ?

Comment: No, not really, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `kable_styling()` and `row_spec()` from `kableExtra`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    style: ./Table.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
```

<div class="table-header-rotated">

```{r test, result="asis"}
kable(head(mtcars), "html") %>%
kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
  row_spec(0, angle = -45)
```
````

**yields:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work with bigger columns. Insert a `mtcars <- add_rownames(mtcars, "model")` before rendering the table and you will see that the rotation misplaces the column header.

Comment: Also this does not make columns any narrower, if the width of the column was due to the long column header

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the html output you can use `gsub` to edit the appropriate lines to match the required `class`, `div` and `span` calls, and then use `cat` to return the edited output. I couldn't get the `css` to work exactly as shown on the link, but the approach below taken from [here](https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/) did rotate the labels:

First block prefaced with ```{css}

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}

th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```
x <- kable(head(mtcars), "html")

x %>% 
  gsub('<th style="text-align:(left|center|right);"> ([^(>| )]+) </th>', 
       '<th class="rotate"><div><span>\\2</span></div></th>', x = .) %>% 
  cat(., sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! Just wanted to add that one needs `{r, results='asis'}` for the second chunk.